# Lines overlapping each other in the app after scrolling

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Today I installed the Stack exchange app in my Samsung Galaxy s Duos s7562.  Whenever I scroll a question and answer block, the letters are overlapping

This is not happening to the code block.

[image]

Comment: @ben is uǝq backwards Thanks for you edit, which is know very clear and precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with lower-end Ice Cream Sandwich phones stating that they supported hardware acceleration when they really did not (or supported only a small subset of it), as of version 1.0.6 this has been fixed, thanks!

Comment: Great and awesome work,  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With February 2, 2014 latest update, the [above issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218272/233367) is fixed.  Now it is looking good.

Thanks.